# Unable to ssh with fedora

Tags: ssh, fedora

I'm new do Fedora and when ever I install the operating systems I am never able to ssh. Whenever I do something like  ssh [email]git@github.com[/email] , I get this error Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known.
I'm able to  do 'host github.com' and do 'ping github.com'
Both respond as you would expect with the ip.

Comment: Can you please post the output of ssh -v and the full command you are trying to try?

Comment: [anarr@localhost ~]$ ssh -v
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0d-fips 8 Feb 2011
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]

Comment: [anarr@localhost ~]$ ssh git@github.com
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
[anarr@localhost ~]$

Comment: can you show us the output of iptables -L? pretty weird if you can ping the hosts (and it responds) but you can't access it..

Comment: Also, can you please post the line from /etc/nsswitch.conf that starts with hosts, plus the current content of /etc/hosts

Comment: #hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns

Comment: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled? Run 'getenforce'.

Comment: getenforce says ENFORCING

Answer (score -1):

Your ssh may try to resolve IP6 and time out doing this. If you are not using IP6 try disabling IP6 in /etc/ssh/ssh_config by changing AddressFamily from 'any' to 'inet'.